# Which is the preferred non-grid based CSS framework?

Tags: css, xhtml

Which is the preferred non-grid based CSS framework? for a start-up of any project.

I want to use a framewrk to save time but without using grid approach. because i don't make design . i work with different proportions.

Comment: I would try rephrasing the question, or adding some specific criteria defining what you need.

Comment: I want to use some ready made css base but don't want to use grid based approach

Comment: I think the problem you're likely to encounter (other than the question being closed fairly promptly) is that almost all (all that I know of, anyway) CSS frameworks are grid-based. I'm struggling to think of another way in which they *could* be based, given that web-pages are, essentially, grids of box-model-based content.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll definitely need for every project is a reset CSS.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

http://code.google.com/p/spared/source/browse/trunk/spared/css/blueprint/src/reset.css